# php mail function is not working in yii

Tags: php, yii

PHP mail function is not working in yii framework www.test.com/index.php?r=Email

```
class EmailController extends Controller {
    public function actionIndex(){
       $this->sendEmail();
    }
    public function sendEmail(){
        mail('test@gmail', 'hello', 'today i am very unhappy');
    } 

}
```

But mail function is working in simple file example www.test.com/email-test.php

Comment: Check your configuration file you may have email turned off in frame work.

Comment: Yii cannot change mail function behavior, your problem is elsewhere... Are you sure you are using the same code in `email-test.php` ? Are you sure it is the same php config ?

Comment: yes bro i am sure.......

Comment: @belive me you have good idea about formating ....

Comment: in your rules did you enable the mail function ? and for which roles did you enable it.

Comment: @gunnit : you mean email action (since you cannot enable/disable mail function using yii rules) ?

Comment: What do your logs says?

Comment: no any error in log some person are saying not enable mail sorry friend this is not issue currently mail is working i am using svn when i restart my php then it is working

Answer (score 1):

Ok if your email function is not working for www.test.com/index.php?r=Email but is working for www.test.com/email-test.php than it has to do with the URL rules in your main config file.

try the following;

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                    'showScriptName'=>false,
                    'caseSensitive'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
                        'gii'=>'gii',
                   '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>', 
                        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                        '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

or try this

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

this goes in your main config file under protected.